# LazyDocs - Generated *.md files do not represent bullet list

Tags: python-3.x, docstring

I hope I am right here in this channel/tag.

I am using [lazydocs](https://pypi.org/project/lazydocs/) for automatic generation of my md files.
My project is written in Python 3.7.5.

I do have some bullet lists in my docstrings.
According to this [example](https://github.com/mkdocstrings/mkdocstrings/issues/135) I need to leave a blank line, then 4 spaces and e.g. "-" follows, end of bullet list another blank line.

Here an example:

```
"""This is my example docstring

A simple bullet list:

    - point 1
    - point 2
    - point 3

"""
```

But when I generate my md file using `lazydocs` the md file looks like:

```
This is my example docstring

A simple bullet list:

    - point 1    - point 2    - point 3
```

I would expect my md file to look like

```
This is my example docstring

A simple bullet list:

    - point 1
    - point 2
    - point 3
```

Then I tried a bit around. I found out that leaving a blank line between the bullet items makes `lazydocs` generate my md5 file in the expected format.
That would look like this:

```
"""This is my example docstring

A simple bullet list:

    - point 1

    - point 2

    - point 3

"""
```

But inserting blank lines into my code is not a nice way to document my code I guess :)

**So my question:**

Am I doing something wrong here or is `lazydocs` not processing the bullet points correctly?

Thanks a lot for any help here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just released a new version of `lazydocs` (0.4.4) with support for bullet lists. You can upgrade via:

```
pip install --upgrade lazydocs
```

The correct way of using bullet lists in this version of `lazydocs` would be without indentation:

```py
"""This is my example docstring

A simple bullet list:

- point 1
- point 2
- point 3

"""
```